# Is it possible to preview a graph when referring to it by hovering as of 2019?

Tags: hyperref, tex-core

I read a lot about `fancytooltip` package but it seems to be a little bit too confusing installing everything.

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is "yes, use the `fancytooltips` package". However, from the body of your question it seems that your actual question is "how do I install and use `fancytooltips`?" If this is indeed the case then you should specify the question a bit further. What did you try to install/use the package? Where did it go wrong? Which parts of the installation did you find confusing? Also, could you provide a small example document with a graph and a reference that can be used as a basis for an answer?

Comment: My question is rather, is there a simpler solution than `fancytooltips` as of 2019. Each post I find about `fancytooltips` is very old.

Comment: What do you consider a "simpler solution" here?

Comment: A simple solution is characterized by not needing to install multiple packages manually , installing Perl, getting to know how Perl works, changing from Biblatex back to natbib because Biblatex is not supported, etc. thus a simpler solution is one package, one executable file, or one script, downloadable as a bundle, serving one purpose. And I almost forgot to mention the need to create a separate Tex document in which all the previews need to be added manually... moreover only Adobe is supported. It it seems like writing a python script doing that automatically is easier than fancytooltips